# Analysis of continuity and differentiability of a function

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Find a,b,c $\in \mathbb{R}$ for which the function is a) continuous, b) differentiable.

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
ax^2+bx+c & x<0 \\
2\sin x+cos x & x\:\ge 0
\end{array}\right.$$

From what I know a function is continuous when the following occurs:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+\:}f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^-\:}f(x) = f(0).$$

Calculating the limits would lead me to $c=1$, but what about a and b?

What do I do for proving that it is differentiable? Because from what I know, a function is differentiable when $f'(x_0)$ *is a finite number*. But I get that $f'(x_0)=2$ which would mean I can have any $a,b,c$?

Comment: How did you get to $f'(x_0) = 2$? Did you forget that $f'(x) = 2ax + b$ for $x>0$?

Comment: Well $x_0=0$ which only exists for the second case of the function, when $x\ge0$. So I calculated for that part of the function.

Comment: So, in that case, the function $f(x)$, defined as $f(x) = x$ for $x<0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x\geq 0$, is differentiable at $x=0$?

Comment: Ugh, had an error when I wrote my function. $f\left(x\right)=2sin\left(x\right)+cos\left(x\right)\:for\:x\ge 0$ So when I differentiated this I got $f\left(x\right)=2cos\left(x\right)-sin\left(x\right)\:which\:for\:x=0\:equals\:2$

Comment: @MikhaelM Technically there are two details to fix in your statement about continuity. The first one is that the equality chain is only relevant for continuity _at 0_, whereas a similar equality chain with $x_0$ instead of 0 is relevant for continuity at $x_0$. The second is that the equality chain is only relevant if the domain of $f$ has 0 as a [limit point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) or "accumulation point", whereas if 0 is an isolated point of the domain of $f$ then $f$ is automatically continuous at 0.

Comment: Naturally, 0 is a limit point of $\mathrm{Dom}\,f$ in this case, as $\mathrm{Dom}\,f=\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For continuity, following your track we get $c=0$, since for $x=0$ the lower branch is $2\sin0\cos0=2\cdot0\cdot1=0$, thus $ax^2+bx+c$ should give 0 in 0, which means $c=0$.

For differentiability, we need continuity, as [Jose's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1351146/135592) states. So $c=0$. Then, we need the derivative to be continuous. The derivative here is:
$$f'(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
2ax+b & x<0 \\
2\cos(2x) & x>0
\end{array}\right..$$
Note that the lower branch is $\sin(2x)$, whence the above derivative. Now the lower branch is 2 in 0, so we must get 2 from above. This implies $b=2$. $a$ is therefore totally undetermined.

To sum up, $f(x)$ is continuous iff $c=0$, and so:
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
ax^2+bx & x<0 \\
\sin(2x) & x\geq0
\end{array}\right..$$
And it is differentiable iff $b=2$, thus being of the form:
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
ax^2+2x & x<0 \\
\sin(2x) & x\geq0
\end{array}\right.,$$
with derivative:
$$f'(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
2ax+2 & x<0 \\
2\cos(2x) & x\geq0
\end{array}\right..$$

Note: It *is* true that differentiability does not generally imply continuity of the derivative. However, a derivative cannot have a jump discontinuity, and being the derivative here bounded from both sides that is the only possible discontinuity we could get, which means that for $f$ to be differentiable it must indeed be $\mathcal{C}^1$.

**Edit:**
The question was missing a plus in the lower branch, and the plus was edited in after I posted this answer. The arguments are the same, but for continuity we get the lower branch giving $2\sin0+\cos0=1$, so $c=1$, and for differentiability we have:
$$f'(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
2ax+b & x<0 \\
2\cos x-\sin x & x>0
\end{array}\right.,$$
which implies the lower branch in 0 is $2\cos0-\sin0=2\cdot1-0=2$, so $b=2$ again. Then $f$ is continuous iff $c=1$, with upper branch $ax^2+bx+1$, and $f$ is differentiable iff it has $c=1,b=2$, and is thus of the form:
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
ax^2+2x+1 & x<0 \\
2\sin x+\cos x & x\geq0
\end{array}\right.,$$
with derivative:
$$f'(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
2ax+2 & x<0 \\
2\cos x-\sin x & x\geq0
\end{array}\right..$$

Comment: Ugh, terribly sorry but the lower branch is $2sin\left(x\right)+cos\left(x\right)$. I edited my post about 10minutes ago when I saw the error. Thanks for the answer though, trying to understand it now.

Comment: @MikhaelM see the edit.

Comment: What about a? Can it be any real number? And how would I show that the function is twice differentiable? Would that give me a finite value for a, thus having a single pair (a,b,c) for which the function is differentiable twice?

Comment: @MikhaelM well for the function to be continuous or differentiable the parameter $a$ is completely free, but still it must be real and finite (unless you want to go into complex numbers but I guess that is not the case, and infinite coefficients are generally not considered as possible). For $f$ to be twice differentiable you write the second derivative and again impose its continuity.

Comment: $f''$ should be $2a$ for $x<0$ and $-2\sin x-\cos x$ for $x>0$, and imposing continuity gives $2a=-2\sin0-\cos0$, that is $a=-\frac12$.

Comment: And I guess this function cannot be any more regular than that, so it cannot be made more than twice differentiable because you don't have enough parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Differentiability implies continuity.

Comment: Yes it does. And you should read more carefully @wythagoras, since what you refer to is a couterexample to the opposite implication, i.e. continuity implies differentiability.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris I misread your hint, sorry. (+1)